# Selection and theming color combination

Tags: autodesk-forge

I set selection color (for example red):
`viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0));`

And at objects with no theming color it is red (roof):
[image: selected roof]

But if theming color is set for objects, selection is far away from red (level 2):
[image: selected level 2]

How to make selection color to override theming color?

Comment: Could you share the theming colors in RGB what you used in this snapshot?

Comment: If I understand this issue correctly, you want the color of the selection overlay is always red, but the selection color is more like the theming color of the selected colored object, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I want selection color to be always red, but I get some mixed highlighting.

Comment: In 3 version you had 'selectionType' parameter, but in 6 version it doesn't affect anything (it seems that now in source code there is code for old 'OVERLAYED' type, but in 3 version 'MIXED' was default and I want such behavior in 6 version)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I will consult this with our engineering team and get you back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Please try viewer version 6.5 and above. Just got confirmed, this issue has been fixed since then.

My apologies for the delay.

======================================

Thank you for feedback and confirming.

Since I can reproduce the issue as you described on my side, I have logged it as `LMV-4004`in our internal case system to our engineering team to allocate time to investigate what happened. Please remember the LMV prefixed id for future reference.

You're welcome to provide additional information to us or ask updates of this issue via sending an email to Forge Help quoting the id in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Has the issue been resolved? I am encountering the same issue in v6 of the Viewer.

Comment: Yes, please use v6.5 and above