# setThemingColor and setSelectionColor unwanted blending

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on coloring individual objects from the viewer with `setThemingColor`, which works by getting the leaf node dbids. We are also using a custom selection color via `setSelectionColor`.

The issue is that when you select a themed object, the resulting color is a blend between the selection and themeing color.

I found another similar question - [Selection and theming color combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362389/selection-and-theming-color-combination), however no solution is listed there, only that it is logged in Autodesk's internal support with ID - LMV-4004.

My issue is exactly the same as the question above, but seeing as the question is more than a year old, I opted to posting a new one.

We are using Viewer v6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Viewer v6.5 and above. The issue LMV-4004 has been resolved by our engineering team since then. Thanks!